# Rootless Docker: Permission denied when writing files to volume mount without sudo

Tags: docker, file-permissions, docker-volume, rootless

I'm unable to write to a mounted volume when in my container (through ssh) without sudo permissions. The mounted folder is host user's home folder at the host. I'm running a rootless docker daemon.

I did the following steps to start a container:

1. I've set up a rootless docker following the instruction on https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/
2. Build the Dockerfile (below) with this command:

   docker build --build-arg USER_ID=$(id -u) --build-arg GROUP_ID=$(id -g) --build-arg USER_NAME=user--build-arg USER_PASS=user -t test .
3. Started a container using the command:

   docker run -d --name test_container -p 50000:22 -v /home/$(id -u -n):/mnt/home test
4. Ssh'd into my container via

   ssh user@localhost -p 50000

When I create a file in my home directory I get a permission denied. When I create a new folder in my host and chmod it to 777; then I'm able to create files but they don't appear in my original host with the proper user/group, instead I get something like:

```
drwxrwxrwx  6 gdekkers gdekkers 4096 May 25 21:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 gdekkers gdekkers 4096 May 25 21:10 ..
drwxrwxrwx  3 gdekkers gdekkers 4096 Apr 30 13:01 SomeFolder
drwxr-xr-x  2   100999   100999 4096 May 25 21:08 test
drwxr-xr-x  2   100999   100999 4096 May 25 21:10 test2
```

which is inconvenient as I need to apply chown periodically. It seems to be related to the namespaces that a rootless Docker uses. How could I make sure that the files that are created match the user at my host?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.2.2-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04

# Input arguments
ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID
ARG USER_NAME
ARG USER_PASS

# environment variables
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
ENV TZ Europe/Belgium

# Install some basic utilities and clean up
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nano \
    ca-certificates \
    sudo \
    libx11-6 \
    openssh-server \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create a sudo user
RUN groupadd --gid $GROUP_ID user
RUN useradd -rm -d /home/$USER_NAME -s /bin/bash --uid $USER_ID --gid $GROUP_ID -G sudo $USER_NAME
RUN usermod -aG sudo $USER_NAME
RUN echo $USER_NAME:$USER_PASS | chpasswd

# Start ssh service
RUN service ssh start
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered problems like this recently when working on my own projects. This is caused by different UID/GID mapping when using Docker rootlessly.

I have a recent write-up on my blog detailing how to deal with [rootless Docker issues such as these "Permissions denied" issues](https://joeeey.com/blog/rootless-docker-avoiding-common-caveats/#storage-fixes). Inheritance ACLs on the host are a viable solution (as also mentioned in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140911/can-i-control-the-owner-of-a-bind-mounted-volume-in-a-docker-image)):

> Start by installing the `acl` package if you do not already have it
> installed:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install acl
> ```
>
> Then let's always allow `rwX` permissions [for current and future
> files](https://serverfault.com/a/778044) in `./data` for the user
> `ubuntu`:
>
> ```
> sudo setfacl -Rm d:u:ubuntu:rwX,u:ubuntu:rwX ./data
> ```

(above example assumes Docker bind mount is a child of `./data`)